# How to get dirent to ignore current directory?

Tags: c++, file

I am working on a C++ program on Ubunutu 16.04 linux 
 It is to read a directory path and group width from shell. It should then navigate through the directory and keep track of files, if it finds a directory go in it and track those files as well. And print a histogram at the end

I have an odd bug that causes a seemingly infinite loop due to the recursive function I have that handles sub folders. If I run the comparison `((J -> d_type) == DT_DIR )` where struct dirent*J. It always returns true once all the files are read because it calls itself over and over again.

Is there any way to prevent that? I feel like an extra check should be all that I need but I don't know what to check. I implemented it via a struct linked list the code for the struct is below:

```
struct node{
    node* next, *prev;
    int count, name, min, max;
    node(){
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
        count = 0;
        name = nodecount;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
    }
}
```

;

And the source code is as follows:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    // Ensures that a valid directory is provided by the cmd line argument
    if (argc != 3){
        fprintf (stderr, "%d is not the valid directory name \n", argc);
        return 1;
    }
    DIR * cwd; // current working directory pointer
    struct dirent *J; // pointer to dirent struct
    int binWidth; // variable for the width of the grouping in the histogram
    binWidth = atoi(argv[2]);
    node *first = new node;
    nodecount++;
    first->max = binWidth - 1;
    node * current;
    current = first;
    bool isadirectory = false;
    if((cwd = opendir(argv[1]))== NULL){
        perror("Can't open directory");
        return 2;
    }

    while ((J = readdir(cwd)) != NULL){
        isadirectory = false;
        if((J -> d_type) == DT_UNKNOWN ){
            struct stat stbuf;
            stat(J->d_name, &stbuf);
            isadirectory = S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode);
        }
        else if((J -> d_type) == DT_DIR ){
            isadirectory = true;
        }
        else{
            if((J-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(J->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                    current->count = current->count+1;
            }
            else if(J->d_reclen < current->min){
                node*temp = current->prev;
                while(temp->prev != NULL){
                    if((J-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(J->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                            current->count = current->count+1;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(J->d_reclen < current->min){
                        temp = current->prev;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                nodecount++;
                current -> next = nextNode(current);
                current = current -> next;
            }
        }
        if(isadirectory){
            traverseNewDirectory(current,J->d_name);
        }
    }
    while ( ( closedir (cwd) == -1) && ( errno == EINTR) );
    printHistogram(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for `strcmp(j->d_name, ".") == 0` and ignore the directory if true.

Horribly undescriptive name, `j`, by the way.

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to ignore the case of `strcmp(j->d_name, "..") == 0`.

Comment: Both of you are right. Sorry about the undescriptive var name. My creativity was wanning at early morning hours. I'll take that into consideration for a refactor.